# invokeAll в CompletableFuture

Tags: java, многопоточность, completablefuture

Моя задача загрузка файлов асинхронно используя ExecutiveService и CompletableFuture, при этом нужно будет измерить время выполнения при 2, 4, 8 потоках и без параллелизации

У меня есть такой метод:

```
File folderWithJson = new File(pathToFolderWithJson);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);


Set<Callable<Boolean>> callables = new HashSet<>();
for(File file: Objects.requireNonNull(folderWithJson.listFiles())) {
    callables.add(() -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getFineToStat(file);
    });
}
executorService.invokeAll(callables);
executorService.shutdown();
```

И он отлично работает, но таким образом я не использую CompletableFuture
, я опробовал такой метод:

```
File folderWithJson = new File(pathToFolderWithJson);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

for(File file: Objects.requireNonNull(folderWithJson.listFiles())) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            getFineToStat(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }, executorService).join();
}
executorService.shutdown();
```

Но у меня при разных количествах потоков получается почти одинаковое время, хотя у меня 31 файл суммой на 850мб, разница должна быть

Так к чему я веду, как мне реализовать invokeAll, но используя CompletableFuture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно использую комбинацию методов allOf() и join()/get(). Первый формирует композитный CompletableFuture из массива, любой из вторых ожидает завершения задач(и)

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    for(File file: Objects.requireNonNull(folderWithJson.listFiles())) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> task = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                getFineToStat(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }, executorService);
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    allFutures.join();
    executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: Вау! Все отлично работает, но если Вам не сложно, могли б подробней описать происходящее?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вам не понятно. По сути allOf это аналог invokeAll. И чтобы дождаться исполнения всех тасок, используется join для объекта CompletableFuture, который состоит из множества объектов CompletableFuture. Т.е. join ждет, пока все эти таски не закончатся.

Comment: Понял, просто голова уже не варит)
И если не смутит вопрос, без параллелизации это простое выполнение метода?